# HTML Component of jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am reading the documentation on the jQuery website about the $.ajax() method and I didn't see an example of the HTML. I'm wondering how you tie the $.ajax() function to a user's "Click" on the submit button. This is my best guess, is it the right way?

Here is the example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="my_form">
<input type="text" name="name"><br />
<input type="text" name="email"><br />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascipt**

```
submit: function {
var form_data = $("form#my_form").serialize();

function progress() {
    //some loading gif
};

function removeProgress() {
    //remove the loading gif
};
$.ajax ({

    type: "GET",
    url: "contact-us.php",
    data: form_data,
    beforeSend: progress(),
    error: function() { alert("dude, something went wrong!"); },
    success: function() { alert("WIN!"); },
    complete: function() { 
        removeProgress();
        alert("1 row added."); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind the function to an event triggered by an element. For example, to bind a function to the `submit` event of the `<form id="my_form">` element, you would do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ..
    $('#my_form').submit(function (event) {
        // ajax call here
    });
});
```

In order to prevent the form from posting to a page (as it would normally do), you would need to add a call to `preventDefault()` on the `event`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // ..
    $('#my_form').submit(function (event) {
        // ajax call here
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole `$.ajax` in a function and bind it in the form's submit handler:

```
function submitForm()
{
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
}


<form ... onsubmit="submitForm(); return false">
</form>
```

The `return false` is important! Or else you'll be calling the default submit of the form too.

**EDIT**

rfausak's answer is better